# Calculating gradient by numerical approximation

Tags: python, numpy, vector, gradient, floating-accuracy

I'm trying to calculate the gradient of a given function by the following definition:[image]

I'm trying to do that with the following code:

```
def numerical_diff_gradient(func, vector: np.matrix, epsilon):
    vec_len = vector.shape[0]
    assert vector.shape[1] == 1
    assert vec_len > 0
    gradient = np.matrix(np.zeros((vec_len, 1)), dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(vec_len):
        base_vector = np.matrix(np.zeros((vec_len, 1)), dtype=np.float64)
        base_vector[i, 0] = 1
        func_plus = func(vector + (epsilon * base_vector))
        func_minus = func(vector - (epsilon * base_vector))
        gradient[i, 0] = ((func_plus - func_minus) / (2 * epsilon))
    return gradient
```

The problem is that I cannot handle very small values since epsilon is between 0 to 2e-60,
hence the variables func_plus and func_minus get the same value and as a result I get that the gradient is a zero vector. How can I represent very small values and keep on their accuracy?

Comment: Typically you can achieve greater accuracy with complex step differentiation, see, e.g., https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2013/10/14/complex-step-differentiation/